# Issue with xib files for iPad universal

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, xib

I have a running iPhone app and I am trying to change it into an universal app in Xcode 3.2. I only want to create new xib files for iPad.

So I simply expand Targets click “Project\Upgrade Current Target for iPad” and choose “One universal application”.

On my app I have a lot of xib files and I want to creat new iPad xib files for the same controller, for example I want to target mainpage-iPad.xib to the controller mainpage.m

In IB for the mainpage-iPad.xib I set the class to "mainpage", that seems to be not enough, whenever I run ipad simulator, I always get the view resized as iphone.

Can you point out what I am doing wrong and suggest the proper way to target the xib file to my controllers.

thanks

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can create iPad specific xibs very simple from existing standard iPhone xibs:

- open iPhone xib in Interface Builder
- in `Menu` of Interface Builder select `File` and `Create iPad version` (or `Create iPad version using Autosizing Masks`)
- save the new iPad xib and add it to your project; the name of iPad xib should be the same as iPhone xib with `~ipad` suffix - e.g. if your iPhone xib is `MyViewController.xib` your iPad xib should be `MyViewController~ipad.xib` (use `~ipad` instead of `-iPad`)

After that your iPad xibs will be automatically used on iPad. Of course you will also need to upgrade your project to a Universal Application (just like you said).

Comment: Changing the name to have suffix ~ipad instead of _iPad worked for me, thanks.